# Bounty count error

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

How does the maths are done ? See the error bellow :

3 active bounties for 250 rep, counter on the right is a 4 bounties and 350 rep...

[image: bounty count image]

Comment: Not just you so I suspect more than the usual reason of caching - or maybe this time more complex caching

Comment: If I were coding it (and I didn't), I'd probably only poll every 15 minutes or so or perhaps every 1000 views and/or 15 minutes. It sure looks like a caching issue to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching delay.

[image]

It's resolved now.

Comment: Solved, ok. But this will occurs again in the future, isn't it ?

Comment: @Samoth Every time a bounty starts or expires - there is a window where this will be wrong. If you're looking for a project, you could re-implement the code ;-) See [Community Promotion Ads](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/community-promotion-ads-2014) _(Also note I said "resolved" and not "solved". She who solves the caching problem would be a queen amongst programmers.)_.